# How do I get the *actual* default database location in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, scripting, configuration

In SQL Server Management Studio, there is an option to set the default database path for a given instance:

[image]

This works.  When I say

```
CREATE DATABASE test
```

it gets created in the path I specify, `E:\data`.  Great.

But how do I get this path in T-SQL (for use in setup scripts)?

[Contrary](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/sql-server-default-folder-locations/) to what [many pages](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/532718/ssms-server-properties-change-database-default-locations-does-not-generate-valid-script-commands) [say](http://gvphubli.blogspot.com/2008/04/default-database-file-path.html), there is no registry key (on my machine) for `DefaultData` or `DefaultLog`.  I am running SQL Server 2005 Express on XP 64.

This value has got to be stored somewhere.  Where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have access to SQL Profiler?

I don't have SQL 2005 Express installed but when I view that properties page on my machine with Profiler running I can see where SQL Server retrieves it from on my SQL 2008 instance.

```
declare @SmoDefaultFile nvarchar(512)

exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
 N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', 
  @SmoDefaultFile OUTPUT

select ISNULL(@SmoDefaultFile,N'') AS [DefaultFile]
```

**Edit:** The above also works for me on SQL Server 2005 Developer edition but only after I changed the default path to something other than the default.

Comment: By the way, the technique of using the profiler to watch the value is very clever!

Comment: Thanks, this works, on my XP machine, my Vista machine, and a 2008 instance on Windows 7.  (Note that the instance needs to be restarted for the default location to take effect).  Also, this code will return an empty string if the original default location is being used, so a really robust solution would have to read both.  Strangely, this subtree does not appear in the Registry Editor. Fortunately, I don't care about such mysteries at the moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Use [SYS.DATABASE_FILES](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174397%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT df.physical_name
  FROM SYS.DATABASE_FILES df
```

### SYS.DATABASE_FILES.type_desc

- ROWS = mdf location, includes mdf filename
- LOG = ldf location, includes ldf filename

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I didn't mention, I've also seen this suggested.  For me, it returns the original default DB location, **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf**

Answer (score 1):

I have done this like this. The sample is for the any database. When you are not sure what the default location is from within the code you can always create a new temporarely database and remove after using this script:

```
DECLARE @databasetocheck AS nvarchar(128) = 'AnotherTestDb'
SELECT  '[' + @@SERVERNAME + ']' AS [Server Name],
        [sdb].[name] AS [Database Name],
        [saf].[name] AS [Logical File Name],
        [saf].[filename] AS [Full path and name],
        LEFT([saf].[filename], (LEN([saf].[filename]) - LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))) AS [File Location],
        LEFT(RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))))-1)AS [Physical File Name],
        RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))) AS [File Extension]
FROM    [master].[dbo].[sysaltfiles] [saf], [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases] [sdb]
WHERE   [saf].[dbid] = [sdb].[dbid]
AND     [sdb].[name] = @databasetocheck
GO
```

Or:

```
-- Find *.MDF and *.LDF database files and corresponding locations for a all databases
SELECT  '[' + @@SERVERNAME + ']' AS [Server Name],
        [sdb].[name] AS [Database Name],
        [saf].[name] AS [Logical File Name],
        [saf].[filename] AS [Full path and name],
        LEFT([saf].[filename], (LEN([saf].[filename]) - LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))) AS [File Location],
        LEFT(RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))))-1)AS [Physical File Name],
        RIGHT([saf].[filename], (LEN(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([saf].[filename]), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([saf].[filename])) -1))))) AS [File Extension]
FROM    [master].[dbo].[sysaltfiles] [saf], [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases] [sdb]
WHERE   ([saf].[fileid] = 1 OR [saf].[fileid] = 2)
AND     [saf].[dbid] = [sdb].[dbid]
GO
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the OP points out, the `DefaultFile` / `DefaultLog` registry values are *not always present* (eg if they haven't been reconfigured since initial install). Behaviour in this case appears to be to create the database/log relative to the path in which the master db / log files exist.

**Via SMO**

With that in mind I always use SMO (via PowerShell) and use either `.DefaultFile` or failing that the `.MasterDbPath` on the `Server` object, eg:

```
$smoServer = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $sqlServer
$str = $smoServer.DefaultFile
if ($str)
{
    $str;
}else{
    $smoServer.MasterDBPath;
}
```

(see https://gist.github.com/piers7/d8f4a75232e5983f7f5b for full script)

**Via Registry**

I don't think it's *quite* that straightforward if you want to hit the registry directly, because I think the masterdb path is only exposed via the service parameters, and not as a dedicated key in it's own right (might be wrong: never really pursued this much).

**Via TSQL**

Within TSQL there doesn't seem to be a particularly clean way of doing this (using xp_instance_regread requires SA rights, for example, not just db_datacreator - see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/515132/management-studio-generates-scripts-that-use-unsupported-undocumented-procedures).

However, the really simple option here is to just use

```
CREATE DATABASE blah
```

...and let the defaults kick in all by themselves! If you only needed the paths so that you can create the database *and* set filesize/growths at the same time, then you can always just *alter* the database immediately afterwards to achieve the same thing:

```
CREATE DATABASE [$(databaseName)
ALTER DATABASE [$(databaseName)] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'$(databaseName)', SIZE = 204800KB )
```

...without ever having to worry about the paths at all